# Why ${!blabla.blibli} returns true in JSTL even if blabla doesn't exist?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

As mentionned in the title, I don't understand why when the variable blabla does not exist I have:

`${blabla.blabla}` which returns nothing

and

`${!blabla.blabla}` which returns true

I guess that there is an implicit exception catch in the jstl evaluation but I can't understand the inner process and why it does work like this, especially when we have in the language : `not empty`, and other checker components. What is the logic behind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP `EL` is `NULL` friendly, if given attribute is not found or expression returns `null`, it doesn’t throw any exception.

For arithmetic operations, **EL** treats null as `0` and for logical operations, EL treats `null` as `false`.

So when you are trying "!" for the variable which is not found it returns `true`

Hope this helps!